# Insert into parent table and child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My problem is with `@officeident`. In that for each new record inserted into `LicenseHolder` it has the same `officeident`.. this SQL inserts into `OfficeID` the value 1495 for every row. Which was the last identity inserted. Which does not create the parent child relationship.

I think I should be researching a for next cursor. For every insert into `Office` a new row is then added to `LicenseHolder` so I can build the relationship. Or if there is a simpler way or any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @officeident INT

insert into [MembersDB].[dbo].[Office] 
([AddressLine1]
,[AddressLine2]
,[State]
,[PostCode])
select [OfficeMailingAddr],[OfficeMailingAddr],[state],'1' FROM [Members].[dbo].[Main]
SET @officeident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [MembersDB].[dbo].[LicenseHolder] ([Name]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Mobile]
  ,[OfficeNumber]
  ,[LicenseHolderTypeID]
  ,[PartyTypeID]
  ,[OfficeID])

SELECT  
   [OfficeOf]
  ,[OfficeEmail]
  ,[Phone]
  ,'1234'
  ,'1'
  ,'1'
  ,@officeident     --I want like this to be different for each row. 
FROM [Members].[dbo].[Main]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I wrote it off the top of my head, so you might need to debug still:

Basically, i wrote a cursor here, which loops through the results of the table you want to use to insert into the new tables. And then create the 2 new insert records at once... (and then do the same with the next result line from the MAIN table).

```
DECLARE @OfficeMailingAddr as varchar(254), @OfficeMailingAddr as varchar(254), @state as varchar(254), @Name as varchar(254), @Email as varchar(254), @Mobile as varchar(254), @Phone as varchar(254)

declare NewCursor Cursor for
SELECT [OfficeMailingAddr],[OfficeMailingAddr],[state], [Name]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Mobile]
  ,[OfficeNumber] FROM [Members].[dbo].[Main]

open NewCursor
fetch next from NewCursor into @OfficeMailingAddr, @OfficeMailingAddr, @state, @Name, @Email, @Mobile, @Phone
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    insert into [MembersDB].[dbo].[Office] 
([AddressLine1]
,[AddressLine2]
,[State]
,[PostCode]) VALUES (@OfficeMailingAddr, @OfficeMailingAddr, @state,'1')
SET @officeident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [MembersDB].[dbo].[LicenseHolder] ([Name]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Mobile]
  ,[OfficeNumber]
  ,[LicenseHolderTypeID]
  ,[PartyTypeID]
  ,[OfficeID]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Mobile, @Phone,'1234'
  ,'1'
  ,'1'
  ,@officeident)

FETCH NEXT FROM NewCursor INTO @OfficeMailingAddr, @OfficeMailingAddr, @state, @Name, @Email, @Mobile, @Phone
END

Close NewCursor
deallocate NewCursor
```